# Elementary transformation of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ on a nonsingular algebraic surface $X$. Assume that there are $r$ sections $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_r$ of $E$ such that the zeros of the wedge of them is a curve $C$. These sections can give us a morphism from the trivial vector bundle of rank $r$ to $E$. How to show the cokernal of the morphism is a line bundle on $C$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As Francesco Polizzi and Jorgen Rennemo remark, the cokernel is not always a line bundle on $C$.

For example, suppose that the vector bundle is $\mathcal E := \mathcal O(D) \oplus \mathcal O(D)$ for some curve $D$ on the surface.
Note that by construction there is a section $s:\mathcal O\to \mathcal O(D)$ whose
zero locus is exactly $D$.  Now take $s_1 = s \oplus 0$ and $s_2 = 0 \oplus s$.
Then $\wedge^2 \mathcal E = \mathcal O(D) \otimes \mathcal O(D) = \mathcal O(2D)$,
and $s_1\wedge s_2 = s^{\otimes 2}$, whose zero locus is $2D$.  So in this case the curve $C$ of your question is non-reduced (it is equal to $2 D$).  On the other hand,
the cokernel of $S$ is equal to $\mathcal O(D)/\mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O(D)/\mathcal O$,
which is a rank two bundle on $D$, rather than a line bundle on $2 D$.

For another example, consider $\mathcal E := \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O$ on $\mathbf A^2 =$
Spec $k[x,y]$, and let $s_1 = (x,0)$ and $s_2 = (0,y)$.
Then $\wedge^2 \mathcal E = \mathcal O$, and $s_1 \wedge s_2 = xy$ as a section of
$\mathcal O$.  The zero locus of $s_1\wedge s_2$ is the curve $C$ given by $x y = 0$,
and the cokernel of the map $\mathcal O^2 \to \mathcal O^2$ is a line bundle away
from the singularity of $C$, but has a fibre of dimension two at the singular point where 
$x= 0$ and $y = 0$ cross.

So one needs some extra assumptions (which are perhaps implicit in your question),
e.g. that the curve $C$ cut out by the wedge of the $s_i$  is smooth.  (In my first
example $C$ is non-reduced, hence non-smooth, while in my second example it is reduced
but singular.)

Assuming that $C$ is smooth, one argues as follows:

Let $x \in X$, and work locally at $x$, so we let $A$ be the local ring of $X$ at $x$.
The vector bundle $\mathcal E$ is locally trivial, so the section $s_i$ is just a map
$A \to A^r$ given by $1 \mapsto (a_{i,1},\ldots, a_{i,r}).$
Taken together, these $s_i$ give a map $s: A^r \to A^r$ whose matrix is $(a_{i,j})$.
Our assumption that $C$ is a curve (rather than all of $X$) translates to the assumption that det $(a_{i,j})$ is non-zero, and the fact that $C$ is smooth at the point $x$
(if $x$ lies in $C$) translates to the assumption that det $(a_{i,j})$ lies in
$\mathfrak m_x$, but not $\mathfrak m_x^2$.

Now if some $a_{i,j}$ is a unit in $A$, then the map $s_i:A \to A^r$ splits;
a splitting is given by projection onto $j$th factor of $A^r$, followed by
multiplication by $a_{i,j}^{-1}$.  Thus in this case we may quotient out 
both the source and target of $s$ by one copy of $A$ (namely by the $i$th summand
in the source and its image under $S$ in the target) and so replace $r$ by
$r-1$.   Continuing in this way, we reduce to the case in which all the $a_{i,j}$
lie in $\mathfrak m_x$.  But then the determinant of $(a_{i,j})$ lies in $\mathfrak m_x^r$,
hence our smoothness assumption shows that $r = 1$, and so the cokernel is 
indeed free of rank one over the curve $C$.

Comment: That's nice. Another argument when $C$ is smooth could be the following. In my notations, the curve $C$ coincides with the determinantal locus `$M_r:=\{x \in \mathcal{R} \; | \; \textrm{rank}(M(x)) \leq r-1\}$`. By general facts on determinantal varieties one knows that $\textrm{Sing}(M_r)=M_{r-1}$. Since we are assuming $C$ smooth, it follows $M_{r-1} = \emptyset$, that is the rank of $M$ is exactly $r-1$ at every point of $C$ and the cokernel is a line bundle. 

Comment: Dear Francesco, Thanks for your comment.  I'm probably just giving a standard proof of the determinantal variety result you mention (or at least, of a special case of it).  Regards, Matthew

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the problem locally, you can assume $X = \textrm{Spec}(R)$, where $R$ is a Noetherian regular local ring. Therefore you have a short exact sequence

$0 \to R^r  \stackrel{M}{\to} R^r \to I \to 0$,

where the matrix $M$ is given by your sections $s_1, \ldots, s_r$. It follows that the cokernel $I$ is a torsion module supported where the determinat of $M$ vanishes, namely over the locus $s_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge s_r=0$, that is over your curve $C$.

Under some genericity assumptions the rank of $M$ will be exactly $r-1$ at every point of $C$, so the cokernel is actually a line bundle on $C$.

In general, it may happen that the cokernel is not a line bundle, see the answers of Jorgen Rennemo and Emerton.

Comment: EDIT: The following is an example showing that the genericity assumption mentioned in that answer is in fact necessary. The rank of $M$ doesn't have to be $r-1$ at any point, take for instance the case where $X = \mathrm{Spec}\ k[x,y]$ and $E$ is a trivial rank 2 bundle. Let $M$ be given by
$$
M=\pmatrix{x & 0 \\
0 & x},
$$
which gives $M$ rank 0 on the curve $C = \{(x,y) | x = 0\}$. In this case the cokernel of the map $\mathcal{O}^2_X \to E$ is a rank 2 bundle on $C$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But in your example the scheme-theoretic zero locus of $s_1 \wedge s_2$ is the curve $x=0$ counted with multiplicity two, so it is not smooth. For this reason I wrote that some genericity assumptions are needed.

Comment: Right, I misread you, thinking you meant a genericity assumption on the point $P$ instead of the curve $C$.